# Find Column and Filter by text

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code which looks at the current open sheet, looks for column Team Manager and filters text. The headers are on the 3rd row and the column Team Manager might change to TM hence me using wild card.

For some reason, it is not working. Am i missing something?

Here is my code

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindMatt()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, col As Long

Const login = "matroux"
Const header = "T*M*"

Set ws = ActiveSheet
col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(header, ws.Range("3:3"), 0)
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

With ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, col), ws.Cells(LastRow, col))
    .AutoFilter 1, login
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Does the code line `col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(header, ws.Range("3:3"), 0)` raise an error? If not, which value does `col` receive? Maybe there are an other header , let us say, "Timberland" before the necessary one, which is returned...

Comment: So basically it goes to the first column and filters nothing. The first column is called Date so it shouldnt even be filtering that column. It should be filtering column 10. But this column could change but there is no other columns with "T".

Comment: I asked two questions... Can you please, try answering them? Any error? What value `col` has, if no error?

Comment: Sorry I did answer them but prob didnt explain properly. There is no errors, what it does is it filters the first column called Date and does not go find the column called Team Manager and filter that column. That is what i mean it does not work. Col is the column with the heading "Team Manager".

Comment: If filters the column returned by `Match`... Please, place a break point on the code line `LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row` and move the cursor over the `col` variable? What does it display? 1? If so, maybe the first column is not "Date"...

Comment: ok so this is strange, i added the break point and now it works. Removed the break point and everything is working perfect. Very strange, wonder if its a bug?

Comment: How did you call/run the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245539/discussion-between-lalaland-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AutoFilter Data

- I'm not sure why your code didn't work (but works now; my guess would be you had another filter active) but the following illustrates what could go wrong. Also, you need to make sure the correct worksheet is active when using `ActiveSheet`.

```vb
Sub FindMatt()
    
    Const Login As String = "matroux"
    Const Header As String = "T*M*"
    Const HeaderRow As Long = 3
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim Col As Variant ' it could be an error value hence 'As Variant'
    Col = Application.Match(Header, ws.Rows(HeaderRow), 0)
    
    If IsError(Col) Then ' this doesn't work with 'WorksheetFunction.Match'
        MsgBox "Header not found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If LastRow <= HeaderRow Then
        MsgBox "No data in column range.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(HeaderRow, Col), ws.Cells(LastRow, Col))
        .AutoFilter 1, Login
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a much better approach thank you.

Comment: Would it be possible to add another filter after this? So once its found "login", do one more filter in column AB to show all values greater than 0?

Comment: The requirement here was to filter the data by a column. Your follow-up question proves that the approach is somewhat unusual, almost wrong. You usually want to reference the complete (table) range and then filter the range by certain columns. Most importantly, you didn't mention what you want to do with the data (copy, delete... etc.). Best ask another question where you should add the additional requirement and add more information. You can freely add this code and explain what it does and what you need it to do. Many here know how to do it. You can also supply a link to the new question.

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008, I loaded a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72651621/filter-excel-column-twice